# npm install fails when triggered using puppet

Tags: node.js, npm, vagrant, puppet

I want to achieve two basic things in this vagrant-puppet setup.

1. Checkout the source code. [Done]
2. Initiate npm install from the checkout directory. [Fails]

Since npm install would always fails at the toobusy module, I thought it would be a problem with the package provider but then if I ssh into the machine and issue a "npm install" the command works successfully.

My puppet manifest looks like this:

```
class hogger::build inherits hogger::params {
  $node_path = "/usr/local/node/node-default/bin"

  exec { "npm install":
    cwd         => $hogger::params::source_code,
    user        => $hogger::params::owner,
    path        => ["/usr/bin", "/usr/local/bin", $node_path],
    logoutput   => true,
    environment => "HOME=/home/${hogger::params::owner}",
    provider    => "shell"
  }
}
```

The output from puppet agent execution is this:

```
> prepush-githook@0.1.1 install /vagrant/sc-router/sc_router/node_modules/prepush-githook
> prepush_hook_install


> precommit-hook@1.0.7 install /vagrant/sc-router/sc_router/node_modules/precommit-hook
> hook_install

npm WARN engine mongoose-nested-set@0.0.6: wanted: {"node":"< 0.7.x"} (current: {"node":"0.10.35","npm":"1.4.28"})

> toobusy@0.2.4 install /vagrant/sc-router/sc_router/node_modules/carpetjs/node_modules/toobusy
> node-gyp rebuild


> kerberos@0.0.8 install /vagrant/sc-router/sc_router/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing kerberos@0.0.8
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing kerberos@0.0.8
npm WARN engine hawk@0.10.2: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"0.10.35","npm":"1.4.28"})

> bson@0.2.18 install /vagrant/sc-router/sc_router/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


> kerberos@0.0.4 install /vagrant/sc-router/sc_router/node_modules/carpetjs/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing kerberos@0.0.4
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing kerberos@0.0.4
npm ERR! prepush-githook@0.1.1 install: `prepush_hook_install`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the prepush-githook@0.1.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the prepush-githook package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     prepush_hook_install
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls prepush-githook
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/node/node-v0.10.35/bin/node" "/usr/local/node/node-default/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /vagrant/sc-router/sc_router
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.35
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT

> prepush-githook@0.1.1 uninstall /vagrant/sc-router/sc_router/node_modules/prepush-githook
> prepush_hook_uninstall

npm WARN continuing anyway prepush-githook@0.1.1 uninstall: `prepush_hook_uninstall`
npm WARN continuing anyway spawn ENOENT
npm WARN continuing anyway prepush-githook@0.1.1 uninstall: `prepush_hook_uninstall`
npm WARN continuing anyway Exit status -1

> precommit-hook@1.0.7 uninstall /vagrant/sc-router/sc_router/node_modules/precommit-hook
> hook_uninstall

npm WARN continuing anyway precommit-hook@1.0.7 uninstall: `hook_uninstall`
npm WARN continuing anyway spawn ENOENT
npm WARN continuing anyway precommit-hook@1.0.7 uninstall: `hook_uninstall`
npm WARN continuing anyway Exit status -1
npm WARN engine boom@0.3.8: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"0.10.35","npm":"1.4.28"})
npm WARN engine cryptiles@0.1.3: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"0.10.35","npm":"1.4.28"})
npm WARN engine sntp@0.1.4: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"0.10.35","npm":"1.4.28"})
npm WARN engine hoek@0.7.6: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"0.10.35","npm":"1.4.28"})

> bson@0.2.18 install /vagrant/sc-router/sc_router/node_modules/carpetjs/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


> bson@0.0.4 install /vagrant/sc-router/sc_router/node_modules/carpetjs/node_modules/mongoose-nested-set/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson
> node install.js

npm ERR! not ok code 0
Exec[/usr/local/node/node-default/bin/npm install] has failures: true
```

Wonder what I could be doing wrong here.

Comment: Does this work manually from the console? The output advises you to contact the author. Have you done that?